# Bash parsing and shell expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm confused in the way bash parses input and performs expansion.

For input say, `\'"\"hello   world\""` passed as argument in bash to a script that displays what its input is, I'm not exactly sure how Bash parses it.

Example,

```
var=\'"\"hello   world\""
./displaywhatiget.sh "$var"
I got '"hello   world"
```

I understand that the double quotes in `"$var"` tells bash to treat the value of `var` together. However, what I don't understand is when is the backslash escaping and double-quoted parsing for the value takes place in bash's expansion process.

I'm coming from [shell-operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation), and [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions).

Comment: One thing you should try to take away from this is an understanding of the difference between literal quotes and syntactic quotes. Quotes that are syntax (instructions to the shell about how to parse things) and quotes that are data (the actual content stored in your variable, passed to commands, etc) are two very different things -- once something has become data, it can't go back to being syntax without `eval`, `sh -c`, or some equivalent to those happening. This distinction is entirely critical to being able to write secure code in shell, since syntax can run arbitrary commands.

Comment: You might consider [BashParser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) and [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) as additional resources.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Does this re-interpretation happen to any data that is already fixed? i.e I read some arguments that bash performs its magic on and say I pass that as an argument to another call. Will bash perform its magic there or will it still remain as "data"?

Comment: Data does not become syntax again without explicit intervention. Once something is data, it stays data unless it gets into an `eval` call, substituted as a string parsed as script text, etc. Though if you don't use quotes on expansion, you *can* have your data split into smaller words, and those words run through glob expansion.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) actually includes a pretty good explanation, inasmuch as it addresses a question that comes up around folks misunderstanding the boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the interesting things happen in the assignment, `var=\'"\"hello   world\""`. Let's break it down:

- `\'` - this is an escaped single-quote. Without the escape, it would start a single-quoted string, but escaped it's just a literal single-quote. Thus, the final string will start with `'`.
- `"` - this starts a double-quoted string.
- `\"` - an escaped double-quote; like the escaped single-quote, this gets treated as a literal double-quote, so `"` will be the second character of the final string.
- `hello world` - since we're still in a double-quoted string, this just gets included literally in the final string. Note that if we weren't in double-quotes at this point, the space would've marked the end of the string.
- `\"` - another escaped double-quote; again, included literally so the last character of the final string will be `"`.
- `"` - this closes the double-quoted string.

Thus, `var` gets assigned the value `'"hello   world"`. In `./displaywhatiget.sh "$var"`, the double-quotes mean that `$var` gets replaced by `var`'s value, but no further interpretation is done; that's just passed directly to the script.

UPDATE: When using `set -vx`, bash prints the assignment in a somewhat strange way. As I said in a comment, what it does is take the original command, parse it (as I described above) to figure out what it means, then back-translate that to get an equivalent command (i.e. one that'd have the same effect). The equivalent command it comes up with is `var=''\''"hello world"'`. Here's how that would be parsed:

- `''` - this is a zero-length single-quoted string; it has no effect whatsoever. I'm not sure why bash includes it. I'm tempted to call it a bug, but it's not actually *wrong*, just completely pointless. BTW, if you want an example of quote removal, here it is: in this command, these quotes would just be removed with no trace left.
- `\'` - this is an escaped single-quote, just like in the original command. The final string will start with `'`.
- `'` - this starts a single-quoted string. No interpretation at all is performed inside single-quotes, except for looking for the close-quote.
- `"hello world"` - since we're in a single-quoted string, this just gets included literally in the final string, *including* the double-quotes and space.
- `'` - this closes the single-quoted string.

so it gets the same value assigned to `var`, just written differently. Any of these would also have the same effect:

```
var=\''"hello world"'
var="'\"hello world\""
var=\'\"hello\ world\"
var="'"'"hello world"'
var=$'\'"hello world"'
```

...and many others. bash could technically have printed *any* of these under `set -vx`.

Answer (score 2):

The parsing of the `\`-prefixed escape sequences happens *on assignment*:

```
var=\'"\"hello   world\""
```

causes Bash to store the following literal in `$var`: `'"hello   world"`.

On later referencing `$var` inside a double-quoted string (`"$var"`) the above literal becomes a *literal* part of that double-quoted string - no interpretation of the value of `$var` is performed at this point.

What double-quoted strings expand to is treated as a single word (argument) by the shell (after removing the enclosing double quotes, a process called [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal)).

Comment: Is this process visible when setting bash with `set -xv`? Because, what I see is the below, where the backslash is still visible.
`var=\'"\"hello world\""`
`var=\'"\"hello world\""`
`+ var=''\''"hello world"'`

Comment: @htcm8 `set -xv` can be a bit misleading if you don't know how to interpret it. What it does is parse the command line (essentially, figuring out what it means), and then back-translate that into a command line that'd mean the same thing, and print that back-translation. There are many equivalent ways to assign that particular value to `var`, so it just picks one and prints it.

Comment: Great! Is that also the reason why I see the same when calling `./displaywhatiget.sh`? Also, what does bash's quote-removal mean and where does it come in play?

Comment: @htcm8 Yep, what it prints when calling `/displaywhatiget.sh` is, again, an equivalent way of passing that particular string as an argument. Quote-removal happens during the initial parsing pass; in this case its effect is that the two unescaped double-quotes get treated as delimiters rather than part of the final string.

Comment: @htcm8: To add to Gordon's helpful comments: the enclosing double quotes (applies analogously to single-quoted strings) are part of the _syntax_, not part of the _contents_ of the string - they merely act as _delimiters_ for the contents, and are therefore removed once the contents have been determined, before the contents are passed as a single argument to the target command.