# Adding quotes to a String in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to add quotes to a string. Like this:

```
stackoverflow => 'stackoverflow'
```

And then append this string to another variable separated by a 'comma'. like:

**${list} (before appending) => 'stackexchange',.....,'meta'**

**${list},'stackoverflow' => 'stackexchange',.....,'meta','stackoverflow'**

I've tried to do this:

```
            if [ -z "$partition_list" ]
            then

                partition_list="'"${partition}"'"
            else

                partition_list=${partition_list}",'"${partition}"'"
            fi
```

Note: $partition is the variable that I am trying to add quotes to. And $partition_list is the list I am trying to append $partition to.

It didn't work. I get the strings like this: **''\''10099'\''**

**EDIT:**

I am getting the value of partition through this statement:

```
partition=`echo $f | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`
```

Is there a way we can add 'sed' to this statement and add the quotes to $partition?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. What have you tried?

Comment: Must be easy, but I am new to shell scripting, so I couldn't figure it out. 
I've tried to add quotes in the assignment statement itself. But that didn't work.

Comment: *Always* show what you've tried. It isn't enough to say that whatever unknown code you tried doesn't work.

Comment: Added what I've tried.

Comment: Adding the results you got would be very useful as well; "it doesn't work" isn't nearly enough of a problem report. Did you get an error? Did you get unexpected results? Include them in your question.

Comment: Your **EDIT** is a different question.

Comment: Agreed -- with the edit, this is too broad to fit within site rules. BTW, if you're trying to generate Ruby code programmatically -- don't. You'll be much better off using a tool such as `jq` that can generate JSON in bash, and having your Ruby code load the JSON.

Comment: No, I am not trying to generate any Ruby code.

Comment: I'm curious, then -- what syntax *is* this that's using `=>` if it's not Ruby (or a derivative such as Chef)? Or are you using that as non-literal syntax? (Code blocks are supposed to be used for literals, ie. *exact* code or data).

Comment: That is not a syntax. I was just trying to explain my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just this?

```
partition_list="${partition_list:+$partition_list,}'$partition'"
```

The `if` construct is replaced with parameter expansion that includes the comma if `$partition_list` is not null (using `:+`), and the single quotes inside double quotes don't stop the variable from being expanded.

Plus ... *always quote the variables you refer to*. Your idea of `foo=$bar",'"$baz"'"` has the potential to be disastrous because the variables might be expanded through globbing.

So if you DID want to do this with the `if`, it would look more like:

```
        if [ -z "$partition_list" ]; then
            partition_list="'${partition}'"
        else
            partition_list="${partition_list},'${partition}'"
        fi
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand what you said about the IF construct.

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu, improved wording in answer, but you can read more about parameter expansion in the `bash` man page.

Comment: I've tried the two ways you mentioned. Neither works. First approach still gives me results like this: ''\''10099'\''

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu, "doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description. The second approach given is quite certainly correct, if correctly deployed. As it is, we can't tell how you're trying to use it, so we can't tell what went wrong in the attempt.

Comment: When I tried the second approach, the one with the if construct, I get results like this: partition_list=''\''10099'\'','\''10199'\''' . This clearly is not giving me the required results.

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu That suggests there are quotes in the value of `$partition`. Can you show your source data?

Comment: @GordonDavisson This is the result I get when I try to append to the list without putting quotes. partition_list=10099,10199,10699,11199

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu Are you looking at the output from `set -x`? If so, you're actually getting correct results, but they're being displayed in a confusing form. The command `partition_list=''\''10099'\'','\''10199'\'''` will actually set the variable `partition_list` to the value `'10099','10199'`. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655630/bash-parsing-and-shell-expansion/41655880) (especially the UPDATE part), which describes a similar situation.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes! you're right! I am getting the right result Thank you!. But there is a new problem, I am iterating in a loop and collecting all the partitions into the $partition_list. I am able to see that new element is being added to the $partition_list. But, when I echo $partition_list outside the loop, It's null. there is no value in it. This seems very strange to me. Can you please help?

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu, that would be [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu, it would also likely be a new question, since there's no loop in the question above.

Answer (score -1):

How about:
//EDIT: updated for handling spaces.

```
list=('aa xx' 'bb')
res=()
for ix in  ${!list[*]};do
  res+=(\'${list[$ix]}\')
done
res+=("'stackoverflow'")
echo ${res[*]}
```

Comment: What if I want an element containing a space, such as `'stack overflow'`? This solution would split that up.

Comment: I've tried that, but I get the result like this: ''\''10199'\'''

Comment: This is really hopelessly buggy. You're defining `res` as an array, but only modifying and printing the first element -- and, as Benjamin notes, you're string-splitting and glob-expanding your elements, rather than treating them as literal other than the need for quotes. Consider running the code in this answer through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Corrected it, thanks for the pointer to shellcheck.net - did not know that one.